# Netbeans Updater Trouble

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I've installed Netbeans IDE 8.2 at my PC. But I don't know why it also appears "Netbeans Updater" when I open it and every time I want to exit, it appears again and automatically open Netbeans too.

I've already choose "Never"at automatically check updates at Tools

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at proxy settings?

Comment: Not yet. How does it works?

Comment: I've unchecked at "No proxy" but it doesn't work at all